# EventHandler raise Event properly

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I'm trying to better understand how Events and their handler work, but I don't understand why when raising an event it is usually preferred to raise an identical event, that our event itself.
To be more specific, when looking at msdn doc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) it looks like that :

```
class Counter
{
    private int threshold;
    private int total;

    public Counter(int passedThreshold)
    {
        threshold = passedThreshold;
    }

    public void Add(int x)
    {
        total += x;
        if (total >= threshold)
        {
            ThresholdReachedEventArgs args = new ThresholdReachedEventArgs();
            args.Threshold = threshold;
            args.TimeReached = DateTime.Now;
            OnThresholdReached(args);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> handler = ThresholdReached;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> ThresholdReached;
}
```

What I don't understand is why "handler" is created in the `OnThresholdReached` function, instead of having

```
protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ThresholdReached!= null)
        {
            ThresholdReached(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Why should we create this "handler" ?

Comment: @MattWilko - I think that's wrong.  I'm pretty sure the suggestion in the OP would work.  I believe that the reason that a 'copy' of the handler is taken is something to do with thread safety.  I remember looking at this exact same question in the past but I can't remember exactly what I concluded lol...

Comment: My "suggestion" indeed works, but still, I'm pretty sure there's a good reason they want to create this handler ;)

Comment: microsoft doc here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx does it without the 'copying' so if there is something going on it is obviously subtly enough for microsoft to not be consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
    if (ThresholdReached!= null)
    {
        ThresholdReached(this, e);
    }
```

What would happen in multi-threaded code if the handler for `ThresholdReached` is removed after `if (ThresholdReached!= null)`, but before `ThresholdReached(this, e);` is called?

Taking a copy of the handler prevents this situation from occuring and makes the raising of the event thread-safe.